# Loop to create a dataframe for each unique value of a categorical variable in R

Tags: r, loops

I am trying to create a data frame for each country. How can I create a loop to go through the Country variable to do this? My current dataset is small, so I can use piping. This is not practical for a worldwide dataset though.

```
Chile <- life_gdp %>%
  filter(Country == "Chile")
China <- life_gdp %>%
  filter(Country == "China")
Germany <- life_gdp %>%
  filter(Country == "Germany")
Mexico <- life_gdp %>%
  filter(Country == "Mexico")
USA <- life_gdp %>%
  filter(Country == "United States of America")
Zimbabwe <- life_gdp %>%
  filter(Country == "Zimbabwe")
```

Comment: I suspect this might be a case of an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem#:~:text=The%20XY%20problem%20is%20a,root%20problem%20itself%20(X).). Why do you want to do this? I suspect things will actually be easier if they're all in a list of dataframes for instance

Comment: `countries <- split(life_gdp, life_gdp$Country)` will create a list of such tables. Then you could use `countries$Chile` to get the Chile one, for instance.

Comment: Another potential alternative is to use `library(tidyverse); country_list <- life_gdp %>% group_by(Country) %>% group_split()` to get each country's dataframe in a list (although I've just seen that this is basically the same as what @JonSpring suggests; if his solution doesn't solve your problem, please edit your question to include more details)

Comment: Both of these comments were right on the money. Thank you for the help!

Comment: An update on this. I recommend using the **split()** function for this.  I am using ggplot and the **country_list <- life_gdp %>% group_by(Country) %>% group_split()** produces an error **Error: Corrupt x: no names**,